# Ghostscript - PS to PDF - Inverted images problem

Tags: windows, pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I'm trying to convert postscript to PDF using Ghostscript.

Everything is converted ok except in some cases images are for some reason inverted.

Reported bug info: http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691759

Now, they say that this bug was fixed. I downloaded ghostscript 8.70, 8.71, 9.00 and tryed all three versions and result is a same.

GSView shows postscript as it should be and does not invert the images.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What was the exact command you used for the conversion? Can you provide a link to a sample PS file showing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, reading the [comment no. 4 for GS bug 691759](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691759#c4) it looks like this was fixed in Ghostscript's subversion source code repository in r120005 on the 7th of January 2011.

Did you compile Ghostscript r12005 yourself and re-test it? You cannot complain about Ghostscript v8.70, v8.71 or v9.00 -- these were all released bevor SVN r12005. And v9.01 (or whatever release version they will choose next) is not yet out (though it should be within the next 2-3 months according to their schedule).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with `gs` 9.02 on Linux, so here is my solution:

After quite a bit of research, I arrived at a `ghostscript` command line, that seems (to me) to implement a near "pass-through" for images in a PDF, meaning that the images in the "distilled" PDF should remain the same as the ones in the original PDF (*see also [How to tell ghostscript to leave bitmap images alone? - comp.text.pdf](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.pdf/browse_thread/thread/86cfc756bf120b17)*). This, then, would avoid both downsampling, and jpeg-like compression artifacts, - and possible inversions of images - during distilling.

Thanks to the answer by @pipitas in [(#277826) Querying Ghostscript for the default options/settings of an output device (such as 'pdfwrite' or 'tiffg4')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11002313/277826), I could basically look at all possible options for `pdfwrite` - and then I simply tried to disable anything image related. So, the command line is this:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
-dAutoFilterMonoImages=false \
-dAutoFilterGrayImages=false \
-dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
-dDownsampleColorImages=false \
-dDownsampleGrayImages=false \
-dDownsampleMonoImages=false \
-dAntiAliasColorImages=false \
-dAntiAliasGrayImages=false \
-dAntiAliasMonoImages=false \
-dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \
-dConvertImagesToIndexed=false \
-dEncodeColorImages=false \
-dEncodeGrayImages=false \
-dEncodeMonoImages=false \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

I tested this on `ghostscript` 9.02 under Ubuntu; and it worked for me... I can see the question is tagged Windows, so the formatting of the command line is likely to be different - however, I believe the same options can be set also in `gs` under Windows, and they should work.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Yes, the very same options can be set on Windows. The only differences are: `gs` becomes `gswin32c.exe` or `gswin64c.exe` and line continuation character `\` becomes `^`. [On Windows, Ghostscript likes to have path+directory separators as `/` (forward slashes) or as `\\` (double backslash).]